# SL asynchronicity at startup... Strategies?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, asynchronous, startup

I'm far from new at threading and asynchronous operations, but SL seems more prone to asynchronous issues, particularly ordering of operations, than most frameworks. This is most apparent at startup when you need a few things done (e.g. identity, authorization, cache warming) before others (rendering a UI usable by your audience, presenting user-specific info, etc.).

What specific solution provides the best (or at least a good) strategy for dealing with ordering of operations at startup? To provide context, assume the UI isn't truly usable until the user's role has been determined, and assume several WCF calls need to be made before "general use".

My solutions so far involve selective enablement of UI controls until "ready" but this feels forced and overly sensitive to "readiness" conditions. This also increases coupling, which I'm not fond of (who is?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One useful aspect of Silverlight startup to remember is that the splash xaml will continue to be displayed until the `Application.RootVisual` is assigned.  In some situations (for example where themes are externally downloaded) it can be better to leave the assignment of the RootVisual until other outstanding async tasks have completed.

Another useful control is the `BusyIndicator` in the Silverlight Toolkit.  Perhaps when you are ready to display some UI but haven't got data to populate the UI you assign the RootVisual using a page that has a `BusyIndicator`.

Comment: I didn't know about the first. Yes, I'm a noob.

Answer (score 0):

In my oppinion:

- 1st: Render start up UI that will tell the user, that the application did register his action and is runing, (Login window may be?)
- 2nd: Issue neccessary calls for warm up procedures in background (WCF calls and all that) and let user know about progress of tasks that are required to finish before next GUI can be made operable (main window?)

Order of operations is kind of situation specific, but please be sure to let user know what is happening if it blocks his inputs.

The selective enabling of individual controls can look interesting, but user might go for that function first and it will be disabled, so you have to make sure user knows why, or he will be confused why at start it was disabled and when he went there 10mins later it works. Also depends on what is primary function of your program and what function would that disabled control have. If application main function is showing list of books it wouldnt be nice to make that list load last.

Comment: Another great reason to avoid selective enablement... or at least give a "why" as you suggest.